# JavaScript Closure and Scoping issues

Tags: javascript

Could anyone explain to me the following code:

```
var person = (function () {
    var locX = 0;
    return {
        "walk": function () {
            locX++;
        },
        "getLocX": function () {
            return locX;
        },
        "locX": locX
    }
})();


person.locX // output 0

person.getLocX() // output 0

person.walk()

person.getLocX() // output 1

person.locX // output 0    <-------- why it is still 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> person.locX// output 0 <-------- why it is still 0

Because in the object initializer, this property initializer:

```
"locX" : locX
```

takes the **value** of `locX` and assigns it to a property on the object. It doesn't create a link between your `locX` *variable* and the property.

It's exactly like this:

```
var a, b;
a = 1;
b = a;
a = 2;
console.log(b); // 1, of course
```

Assigning `a`'s **value** to `b` didn't create any kind of link between `a` and `b`. It's exactly the same with an object property.

If you want to get the value of the *variable* `locX`, your `getLocX` function is exactly how you would do that.

If your goal is to be able to read `locX` from the object without explicitly calling a function, but have that value come from your variable, in ES5 onward you could use a *getter* function for that:

```js
var person = (function() {
  var locX = 0;
  return {
    walk: function() {
      locX++;
    },
    get locX () {
      return locX;
    }
  };
})();
snippet.log(person.locX); // 0
person.walk();
snippet.log(person.locX); // 1
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

It's important to realize that using a getter function means that `person.locX` is a *hidden* function call.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation,  I noticed that you did not use "" to quote the `walk`, what is the difference between quoted walk and unquoted walk?

Comment: @XuzhengWang Nothing. When the key of object does not contains any special symbol except underscore, you can skip the quotes

Comment: @XuzhengWang: The property name in a property initializer can be any of: 1. A literal that conforms to the *IdentifierName* rules (`walk` does), 2. a string literal (single or double quotes), 3. or a numeric literal. (ES2015 also adds computed names.) So for `walk`, there's no difference, but if you wanted to create a prop called `walk with me` (note the spaces), you'd need to use quotes. Similarly you'd need quotes for a prop called `123abc`, because that's not a valid *IdentifierName*. The rules for *IdentifierName* are the same as for variables, except reserved words are okay too.

Answer (score 2):

> person.locX// output 0 <-------- why it is still 0

Problem is here,

```
"locX" : locX
```

Unlike `getLocX`, only the value `0` was copied at the time of return statement and not the reference of `locX`.

Answer (score 1):

Because changing the value of `locX` variable will not update the value of the property, they are not linked together.

A possible solution is to use [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) as below, so that we can return the value of the local variable whenever the value of the `locX` property is requested.

```js
var person = (function() {
  var locX = 0;
  var obj = {
    "walk": function() {
      locX++;
    },
    "getLocX": function() {
      return locX;
    }
  }

  Object.defineProperty(obj, 'locX', {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function() {
      return locX
    }
  });

  return obj;
})();

snippet.log('locX: ' + person.locX);
snippet.log('getLocX: ' + person.getLocX());
person.walk();
snippet.log('walk')
snippet.log('locX: ' + person.locX);
snippet.log('getLocX: ' + person.getLocX());
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Or as TJ said using [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```js
var person = (function() {
  var locX = 0;

  return {
    "walk": function() {
      locX++;
    },
    "getLocX": function() {
      return locX;
    },
    get locX() {
      return locX;
    }

  };
})();

snippet.log('locX: ' + person.locX);
snippet.log('getLocX: ' + person.getLocX());
person.walk();
snippet.log('walk')
snippet.log('locX: ' + person.locX);
snippet.log('getLocX: ' + person.getLocX());
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: You don't need to use `Object.defineProperty` for this (although you can), there's literal getter syntax.